# Subtraction and collection time in RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I need my time column to give me the output like this
2PM - 2-59PM
so what i need to do is just to  +1 hour and -1 minute to get this value but i don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Basics of SO question.. please show what your raw sample data is for that column. More details you provide the more likely you are get a quicker response!

Comment: Is the column you're referencing a datetime type?